# Azure Search Service search integers

Tags: azure, search, odata, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Providing you have a simple index:

```
public partial class SomeIndex
{
    [Key]
    [IsFilterable]
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable, IsSortable]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [IsFilterable, IsSortable]
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
```

How do I search the exact number matches for SomeNumber int?

`'eq'` doesn't apply here.

Any advice appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating an OData filter query?

Comment: As I mentioned above a query with 'eq' will not find matches.

Comment: I just tried it with an integer type field in an index and it worked perfectly fine. I used REST API directly. I am wondering why do you say it won't find any matches.

Comment: @tom33pr This is unrelated to your question, but you should model your numeric field as type int? not int.  Otherwise null values won’t deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter. 'eq' works perfectly.

The filter query will be 'Field name **eq** number'

The only constraint is that the field must be filterable